# Sharing unsharing files/folders etc via REST API for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, office365

Is there any way we could share/unshare a file or folder with users (external or internal) through REST API?

I am unable to find proper documentation for this. The only information out there is for update, delete, create, download, upload, and read operations!

I have come across some posts which indicate that it's possible to update the fields for a listitem. I was wondering if I could achieve sharing/unsharing through that?

If not sharing then at least unsharing(remove sharing details which ultimately unshares the item). Can unsharing be achieved through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a colleague who is more familiar with the Files API than I am, and he said no file sharing properties are exposed via the Files API for Office 365 - so it looks like it's not possible at this point with that API. You could file a request to add that functionality via [User Voice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/) feedback page.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I've been looking for it all over the Internet. I've one more query regarding Files/Folders, if you may please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792930/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-meta-for-a-deleted-item-file-folder-for-office3

Comment: I took a shot at your other question. Good luck!